# Javascript - Add class to a class (not ID)

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement

In a HTML file i load a javascript file (in the header) which contains some code. In that code it checks if a cookie exists. If the cookie doesn't exists it should add a class to a div which should be matched with a class.

Example:

The class where it should add the class:

```
<header class="firstClass">
```

The javascript:

```
var classcode = document.getElementsByClassName("firstClass");

if (myCookie == null) {
    add class "secondClass" to "firstClass";
}
```

I've tried several things but I can't get it to work...

I should mention, the javascript file is loaded before the div where the class should be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Use `spread operator` to convert it into array and use array methods(`forEach`) in this case. Then check if the array length is greater than 0, if greater than 0 then add another class using `classList.add`

```js
var classcode = [...document.getElementsByClassName("firstClass")];
if (classcode.length > 0) {
  classcode.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.add('anotherClass')
  })
}
```

```css
.anotherClass {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="firstClass">Header Here</header>
<div class="someOtherClass"> Some Text</div>
<div class="firstClass">Another Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use querySelectorAll, in order to find all the elements with the class *firstClass*. This will result in an array, then you just have to loop through it.

```
var classcode = document.querySelectorAll(".firstClass");

classcode.forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.add("mystyle")
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `classList.add()` to each of the elements that has class `firstClass`. Although you might have single element, but it is better to use a loop for selecting each element so that in future when you add element in HTML with this same class then you do not need to change the JS code.

```js
var classcode = document.getElementsByClassName("firstClass");

for(var i=0; i<classcode.length; i++){
   classcode[i].classList.add('secondClass');
}
```

```css
.secondClass{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstClass">1</div>
<div class="firstClass">2</div>
<div class="firstClass">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var classcode = document.getElementsByClassName("firstClass");
if (myCookie == null) {
    classcode .classList.add("secondClass");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all solutions will work. The problem was that I had to load the javascript file after the div which should get the class added. Thanks al for the help! :)